# Protocol with Encodable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, networking, protocols, encodable

I have struct that has parameter with protocol type

```
protocol CheckoutOrder {}

struct CheckoutOrderEntity: Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amount
        case payment
    }
    
    let amount: Int
    let payment: CheckoutOrder
}
```

Also have 2 structs which implements protocol **CheckoutOrder**

```
struct ApplePayOrderEntity: Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case token
    }
    
    let token: ApplePayTokenEntity
}

extension ApplePayOrderEntity: CheckoutOrder { }
```

```
struct CheckoutPaymentEntity: Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case terminalName
        case shouldUseBalance
    }
    
    let shouldUseBalance: Bool
    let terminalName: String
}

extension CheckoutPaymentEntity: CheckoutOrder { }
```

I have an error: *Type 'CheckoutOrderEntity' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'* and *CheckoutOrder protocol requires function 'encode(to:)'...*. So, the main reason of using protocol is that payment can be type of *ApplePayOrderEntity* or *CheckoutPaymentEntity*. ***How to solve problem or what is best practice in this case?***

Comment: The linked question is for arrays, but you can convert it to just handle a single element by using `try container.encode(payment, forKey: .payment)`. It just won't write an automatic conformance for you.

Comment: (You also need to add `: Encodable` to the protocol definition as Joakim Danielson notes. But the deeper issue is that you won't get automatic conformance because the compiler just won't do that today.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make the protocol extend `Encodable` to tell the compiler that anything that conforms to `CheckoutOrder` also conforms to `Encodable`

```
protocol CheckoutOrder: Encodable {}
```

Then I would use generics for this and change `CheckoutOrderEntity` to

```
struct CheckoutOrderEntity<Payment: CheckoutOrder>: Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amount
        case payment
    }

    let amount: Int
    let payment: Payment
}
```

Example

```
let checkout = CheckoutOrderEntity(amount: 1000,
                                   payment: CheckoutPaymentEntity(shouldUseBalance: true,
                                                                  terminalName: "terminal"))
```